# Extracting icons from a single image

Tags: icon, software-recommendation

I have purchased a set of icons.

In the package there are five files that contain all the icons, assembled on a regular grid in different file formats.

The file formats are `.ai`, `.eps`, `.pdf`, `.png`, `.psd`.

I need the icons to use in an android application I'm writing. I need around twenty of them at different resolutions (`32x32`, `48x48`, `64x64` & `96x96`), in `.png` format.

The only way I know to extract the single icons is to do it by hand, but it would be a tedious and error-prone way.

**Is there an automatic method, or a better way of getting the icons out of the files, at the various resolution I need?**

What software will I need?

Ps.
The icons i need to obtain have the following format:

[sample android icon](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/802/66j9.jpg/)

As you can see, the icon is centered in a 64x64 bitmap. I have colored red the transparent part of the image to make it more visible.

Comment: Do you have Adobe Illustrator? Using the .ai file you should be able to copy/paste individual icons into a Photoshop file and save. Not much error can happen there.

Comment: How easy/difficult or automated the processes can be greatly depends upon the configuration of the .ai file.  If each icon is on its own artboard in Illustrator it's a very easy thing. If all icons are on one artboard, copy/paste is about your only solution.

Comment: I have access to photoshop cs6, but not Adobe Illustrator. Could i use Inkscape instead of AI? However, the .psd file is divided into layers, one layer for each icon. I hope this can help! I have tried to create a slice from a single layer, but the slice created is the minimal bounding box of the icon, and i need instead fixed squared boxes (32x32, 64x64 and so on...).

Comment: Ahh, then in Photoshop... size file accordingly, then File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files

Comment: If the .ai files are saved in PDF compatibilty mode they can probably be imported in Inkscape.

Comment: @Scott: size file accordingly what does mean? Could you add some detail? Thx.

Comment: @Takkat: i am able to open the .ai with inkscape, but then what i need to do?

Comment: @lukeluke - make certain the document size is the size icons you want... 32x32, 64x64, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Export objects from Inkscape as bitmaps

To export a vector object imported in Inkscape as a bitmap of defined pixel size we need the following steps:

### Case source icons include background

1. Select the object with the select tool.

   [image]
2. Export the object as bitmap (*"File - Export Bitmap..."*).

   [image]
3. Choose *""Export area - Selection"* to only export the object.
4. Define the pixel size (above 64 x 64) for the resulting bitmap.
5. Choose a path and a filename for export.
6. Done.

   [image]

**Note:** There is a batch option in Inkscape for exporting multiple selected objects in the *"Custom"* option but this will not let you define a fixed pixel size for each object.

### Case source icon objects only

In case the source icons do not include a square box with margins the above steps will lead to a distorted icon when the object has a with different to height. We then need an additonal step to get desired results.

1. Select object with the select tool.
2. Copy the object to clipboard.
3. Open a new document having the size of the source icons. In Inkscape you will have predefined layouts in the *File - New* menu (here I took `icon_32x32`).
4. Paste the clipboard content to the new document.

[image]

5. Align the icon, e.g. to the center using the *"Object - Align and Distribute..."* tool.
6. Export the page as bitmap with *"File - Export Bitmap..."*.
7. Choose *"Page"* and the desired bitmap sizes in the opening dialog (see above). We can export all sizes consecutively.

### [image] 32 [image] 64 [image] 128